# Redfin scraper for getting redfin estimate

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a few posts about this but I have found a new issue. You will notice from [link1](https://www.redfin.com/CA/Laguna-Beach/693-Bluebird-Canyon-Dr-92651/home/4894466) and [link2](https://www.redfin.com/CA/Laguna-Beach/687-Catalina-St-92651/home/4889627) that depending on whether the house is on the market or not the page will have a different way of where the redfin estimate is displayed. I have a way of getting the redfin estimate from link1 but not at link2.

This is the html from link2 where the redfin estimate is stored that I am trying to get:

[image]\

I tried to follow a similar approach to how I am getting link1's data but my code returns an empty list.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webelement
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.redfin.com/')


def get_redfin_estimate(address):
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('searchInputBox')
    search_box.send_keys(address)
    search_box.submit()
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['statsValue'])
    for element in data:
        if "$" in element.text:
            return(element.text)
        else:
            return "N/A"


# print(get_redfin_estimate('687 Catalina Laguna Beach, CA 92651'))

search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('searchInputBox')
search_box.send_keys('687 Catalina Laguna Beach, CA 92651')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and tag.get('class') == ['value'])
print(data)


driver.quit()
```

If anyone has suggestions on how to get link2's redfin estimate that would be greatly appreciated or if you have suggestions on how I get link1's redfin estimate let me know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get redfin Estimate from link2 try the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.redfin.com/CA/Laguna-Beach/687-Catalina-St-92651/home/4889627")
time.sleep(3)
data=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
redfinestimate=soup.find('span',class_='avmLabel').find_next('span', class_='value').text
print(redfinestimate)
```

---

To get the data from link1 use the following code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.redfin.com/")
element=driver.find_element_by_id('search-box-input')
element.send_keys('687 Catalina Laguna Beach, CA 92651')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='inline-block SearchButton clickable float-right']"))).click()
time.sleep(3)
data=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
redfinestimate=soup.find('span',class_='avmLabel').find_next('span', class_='value').text
print(redfinestimate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Selector `.avm .statsValue` for link1 and `[data-rf-test-id="avmLdpPrice"] .value` for link2, combine both using comma `,` to select existing one and use in one selector:

```
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
price = soup.select_one('.avm .statsValue, [data-rf-test-id="avmLdpPrice"] .value').text
price_numeric = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", price)
print(price)
print(price_numeric)
```